# quickest way to swap index with values

Tags: python, pandas

consider the `pd.Series` `s`

```
s = pd.Series(list('abcdefghij'), list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
s

A    a
B    b
C    c
D    d
E    e
F    f
G    g
H    h
I    i
J    j
dtype: object
```

What is the quickest way to swap index and values and get the following

```
a    A
b    B
c    C
d    D
e    E
f    F
g    G
h    H
i    I
j    J
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One posible solution is swap keys and values by:

```
s1 = pd.Series(dict((v,k) for k,v in s.iteritems()))
print (s1)
a    A
b    B
c    C
d    D
e    E
f    F
g    G
h    H
i    I
j    J
dtype: object
```

Another the fastest:

```
print (pd.Series(s.index.values, index=s ))
a    A
b    B
c    C
d    D
e    E
f    F
g    G
h    H
i    I
j    J
dtype: object
```

**Timings**:

```
In [63]: %timeit pd.Series(dict((v,k) for k,v in s.iteritems()))
The slowest run took 6.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 146 µs per loop

In [71]: %timeit (pd.Series(s.index.values, index=s ))
The slowest run took 7.42 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 102 µs per loop
```

---

If length of `Series` is `1M`:

```
s = pd.Series(list('abcdefghij'), list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))
s = pd.concat([s]*1000000).reset_index(drop=True)
print (s)

In [72]: %timeit (pd.Series(s.index, index=s ))
10000 loops, best of 3: 106 µs per loop

In [229]: %timeit pd.Series(dict((v,k) for k,v in s.iteritems()))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.77 s per loop

In [230]: %timeit (pd.Series(s.index, index=s ))
10 loops, best of 3: 130 ms per loop

In [231]: %timeit (pd.Series(s.index.values, index=s ))
10 loops, best of 3: 26.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: It's interesting, i've compared `pd.Series(s.index.values, index=s.values)` with `pd.Series(s.index, index=s)` on 1M rows series - the first one is 5.5 times faster.

Comment: Yes, I dont compare it in large dataframe. I add it to answer.

Comment: I think the fastest solution according to your timings is `pd.Series(s.index, index=s)`, instead of `pd.Series(s.index.values, index=s)`?

Comment: in the last section for 1M length, your first and third `timeit`s show that they're using identical code, but the times are far different. I assume one of them is supposed to be `pd.Series(s.index.values, index=s.values)`?

Comment: Warning: Using `dict` will discard information if there are duplicates in the `Series` values (since those become the `dict` keys in this example). The faster method has the added benefit of avoiding that issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = s.reset_index().set_index(s.name).squeeze()
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
a2b = my_df
b2a = pd.Series(data = a2b.index, index = a2b.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the series and index have names and you want to swap them as well:

```py
srs_1 = pd.Series(list('ABC'), list('abc'), name='upper').rename_axis('lower')
# lower
# a    A
# b    B
# c    C
# Name: upper, dtype: object

srs_2 = pd.Series(srs_1.index, index=srs_1)
# upper
# A    a
# B    b
# C    c
# Name: lower, dtype: object
```