# Python pandas, can I display value_counts() in reverse order?

Tags: python, pandas

If I call

```
print(data[5].value_counts().nlargest(5))
```

And I get the top five results:

```
A     8
C     6
D     5
B     3
E     1
```

What could I could to change the order of the results so it looks like this instead?

```
8     A
6     C
5     D
3     B
1     E
```

Thanks!

Comment: This have potential risk when two values' frequency are same , duplicated index will bring some trouble.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [quickest way to swap index with values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40146472/quickest-way-to-swap-index-with-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swap index and values with `Series` contructor:

```
s = data[5].value_counts().nlargest(5)
s = pd.Series(s.index, index=s.values)
print (s)
8    A
6    C
5    D
3    B
1    E
dtype: object
```